# running groovy step definitions using cucumber framework

Tags: android-studio, groovy, cucumber

I am trying to run Cucumber tests in android studio using groovy step definitions. Why am I getting the following error message in my Run log?

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\BSI-Laptop-2\AndroidStudioProjects\AnotherNewProject\app\src\test\groovy\StepDefinitions.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class cucumber.api.java.en.When
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import cucumber.api.java.en.When
   ^

C:\Users\BSI-Laptop-2\AndroidStudioProjects\AnotherNewProject\app\src\test\groovy\StepDefinitions.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class cucumber.api.java.en.And
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import cucumber.api.java.en.And
   ^

C:\Users\BSI-Laptop-2\AndroidStudioProjects\AnotherNewProject\app\src\test\groovy\StepDefinitions.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class cucumber.api.java.en.Given
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import cucumber.api.java.en.Given
   ^

C:\Users\BSI-Laptop-2\AndroidStudioProjects\AnotherNewProject\app\src\test\groovy\StepDefinitions.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class cucumber.api.java.en.Then
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import cucumber.api.java.en.Then
   ^

4 errors


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please check your build path.

Comment: @Rao - I cannot figure out whats wrong with my build path. Could you take a look at it and see if you can spot the problem? What do you need to be able to do this? Much thanks.